# Javascript : How can i change the date numbers....?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, date, format

So sunday starts with the number 0, but i need to get sunday to 6. so it will look like this :

Monday - 0 
Thuesday - 1 
wednesday - 2
thursday - 3 
friday - 4
saturday - 5 
sunday - 6

But the problem is i dont know how, only thing that worked is making it an array but that is not the assignment..

Anyone knows what to do?

thanks<3

Comment: Do you mean day numbers obtained with getDay() method from Date object?

Comment: Yes the assignment has to start with this: function getLocalDay(date) {
  var day = date.getDay();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the modulus function, like this:

```
(date.getDay() + 6) % 7
```

Comment: Or `(date.getDay() || 7) - 1`. ;-)